# FIXED: C++ server/client program: "Connection refused"

Tags: c++, c, sockets, gdb, client-server

I'm writing a simple program to transfer files from server to client (both on the same computer for now). Using "telnet 127.0.0.1 [port]", I can succesfully get the file from the server, but when I run the client, the server refuses connection. I suspect that the client is trying to connect to the wrong address, but I'm not sure. I also added some GDB test output if it helps.

Server: "./server 0 4100 bigfile 100 0.01"

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int sockfd;
    if(!(sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        error("Failed to create socket");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cl_addr;
    bzero((void*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        error("Failed to bind");
    }
    listen(sockfd, 10);

    int fd = open(argv[3], O_RDONLY);
    int bufsize = atoi(argv[4]);
    int packet_period = atoi(argv[5]);
    size_t cl_addr_len = sizeof(cl_addr);
    char *buf = new char[bufsize];
    while(true) {
        int sd;
        cout << "waiting for client..." << endl;
        if(!(sd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, (socklen_t*) &cl_addr_len))) {
            error("Failed to acccept");
        }
        cout << "Accepted client connection" << endl;
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        while(int n = read(fd, buf, bufsize)) {
            cout << "Transferring " << buf << endl;
            usleep(100000);
            write(sd, buf, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Client: "./client 0 127.0.0.1 4100 bigfile stats"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        error("Failed to open socket");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[3])); // I tried both htons and htonl
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        error("Failed to connect");
    }

    int n;
    char buf[256];
    int fd = open(argv[4], O_RDONLY);
    while((n = read(sockfd, buf, 256)) > 0) {
        printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
        write(fd, buf, n);
    }

    close(fd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

GDB Output:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: [...]/client 0 127.0.0.1 4100 bigfile stats

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=6, argv=0x7fffffffde68) at client.cpp:31
31      if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {

(gdb) p serv_addr
$1 = {sin_family = 2, sin_port = 0, sin_addr = {s_addr = 16777343}, 
  sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
```

Comment: If you are not sure with the address, try to sniff the connection with wireshark

Comment: I'm running both on my computer - the address has to be 127.0.0.1, and port 4100, because I can connect using "telnet 127.0.0.1 4100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{sin_family = 2, sin_port = 0, sin_addr = {s_addr = 16777343}, sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
```

So `sin_port` is wrong: it shouldn't be zero. The code that sets it is:

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htonl(atoi(argv[3]));
```

The problem is here. It should be

```
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[3]));
```

Not today's problem but

```
printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
```

should be

```
printf("Received: %.*s\n", n, buf);
```